# Android scroll whole screen instead of only listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have the following layout structure:

```
RelativeLayout
  -LinearLayout(Vertical)
  |  ...
  |  ...
  -LinearLayout(Vertical)
     ListView
```

The `ListView` has a bunch of items set by an `ArrayAdapter`. Currently, only the `ListView` is scrollable, the first `LinearLayout` stays in its place. However, I want the whole screen to be scrollable, so if the user scrolls far enough, the `ListView` will potentially occupy the whole screen, if there are enough list items.

This image illustrates the desired behaviour (before and after scrolling)[image: Desired layout behaviour before and after scrolling]
The red box is the first `LinearLayout`, and the green box is the `LinearLayout` with the `ListView`

Thank you for your precious help!

Comment: A quick workaround would be to set your first (header) LinearLayout as the first item in LsitView :)

Comment: You can use a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to scroll the entire contents of the screen, but you can't use a scrollable ListView inside that, so your options are limited with that design. I do this in one of my apps, and I had to create a custom ListView where I manually added views to it to make a mock list. The problem with that, though, is you lose the performance and memory benefits of an actual `ListView`.

Comment: I followed the suggestion of setting the header of the listview as the first linear layout and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to use the RelativeLayout you can try a different structure using the CoordinatorLayout like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout >
    <AppBarLayout >
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout >
             <!-- first layout with the property layout_scrollFlags="scroll" -->
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout >
    </AppBarLayout >

    <ListView > <!-- or RecyclerView to be more updated -->
</CoordinatorLayout >
```

If you have to use the RelativeLayout you can choose to implement all in a Scrollview (bad performarce and reinvent the wheel) or you can add your view as a header of the listview

-----EDIT just for clarity here is my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="it.italia.playground.CollapseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding16"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:maxHeight="@dimen/padding16"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/img"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding16"
                    android:text="text title"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_layout"></include>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The CoordinatorLayout did not work. However I followed your suggestion of adding the view as a header of listview and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Like wolfy said, `CoordinatorLayout` is the best option, but `ListView` wouldn't work in that situation because it does not implement the correct callback interfaces needed for communicating with the `CoordinatorLayout`.
How does `CoordinatorLayout` actually coordinate scrolling for its child views?
You need to swich `ListView` for a View which implements the [`NestedScrollingChild`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) interface, you don't actually need to write the code for these methods, views like the `RecyclerView` or the  `SwipeRefreshLayout` take care of that work for you ;)

And in turn `CoordinatorLayout` implements the [`NestedScrollingParent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html) interface which spares you another load of work (google doc):

> This interface should be implemented by ViewGroup subclasses that wish to support scrolling operations delegated by a nested child view.

In case you need a swipe refresh action, `SwipeRefreshLayout` implements both interfaces. Looking at the view hierarchy it sits between the `CoordinatorLayout` and the `RecyclerView` so it can deal with both with the `NestedScrollingChild` and the `NestedScrollingParent`.

Bottom line: Either switch `ListView` for the `RecyclerView` or make ListView implement `NestedScrollingChild`. It should work either way !

Two excellent explanations on dealing with scrolling with the new APi's:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

https://lab.getbase.com/nested-scrolling-with-coordinatorlayout-on-android/

Code [sample](https://github.com/ggajews/nestedscrollingchildviewdemo) for an implementation of `NestedScrollingChild` from a demo.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I'll keep this as reference!

Answer (score 0):

Use a scrolllayout which fits the screen and make the listview wrap the content

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`, then you can wrap the list in a `NestedScrollView` and call `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false)`. On top you can use another `ScrollView` with all that content (*red marked views* in your graphic) and put that `NestedScrollView` (*green marked list*) as a child inside of it.

The `NestedScrollView` takes care of the dynamically set height, otherwise the recyclerView would only use one fixed height. Be aware that, if the list gets too long, it might have an unwanted UI lag, then it's more efficient to set everything as a part of the list in the adapter by inflating different layouts on the list. On the other side, this could be also a bit tricky since the whole layout is now a part of a list and all changes which are done to that needs to go through the adapter.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the **SOLUTION:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--here if you want a fab-->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_edu_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_24dp" />


     <!--starting the scroll of the layout-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--scroll view-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainScrollChild"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <!--start adding your red part-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:padding="1dp"/>                    

            <!--end Red Part-->

            <!--start the green part (recyclerView)-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cardView">

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--end green part-->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]